# Wrong items add to cart

Tags: javascript, html

When I try to add items from other categories other then the first it adds the items from the first category no matter on which category I go and add items each item should be unique so when I add it to cart should be an unique item but every category except the first one adds the wrong items same items all over again

I tried to group differently or to change the category index to direct it not by groups still didn't work

```js
let openShopping = document.querySelector(".shopping-cart");
let closeShopping = document.querySelector(".closeShopping");
let list = document.querySelector(".small-products-list");
let listCart = document.querySelector(".listCart");
let body = document.querySelector("body");
let total = document.querySelector(".total");
let quantity = document.querySelector(".quantity");

openShopping.addEventListener("click", () => {
    body.classList.add("active");
});
closeShopping.addEventListener("click", () => {
    body.classList.remove("active");
});

let productsAll = [
    {
        id: 0,
        name: "Hanorac1",
        image: "1.png",
        price: 1,
        href: "products/hanorac1.html",
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Hanorac2",
        image: "1.png",
        price: 2,
        href: "products/hanorac2.html",
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Hanorac3",
        image: "1.png",
        price: 3,
        href: "products/hanorac3.html",
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "Hanorac4",
        image: "1.png",
        price: 4,
        href: "products/hanorac4.html",
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: "Hanorac5",
        image: "1.png",
        price: 5,
        href: "products/hanorac5.html",
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        name: "Hanorac6",
        image: "1.png",
        price: 6,
        href: "products/hanorac6.html",
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        name: "Hanorac7",
        image: "1.png",
        price: 7,
        href: "products/hanorac7.html",
    },
    {
        id: 7,
        name: "Hanorac8",
        image: "1.png",
        price: 8,
        href: "products/hanorac8.html",
    },
    {
        id: 8,
        name: "Hanorac9",
        image: "1.png",
        price: 9,
        href: "products/hanorac9.html",
    },
    {
        id: 9,
        name: "Hanorac10",
        image: "1.png",
        price: 10,
        href: "products/hanorac10.html",
    },
    {
        id: 10,
        name: "Bluza1",
        image: "11.png",
        price: 1,
        href: "products/bluza1.html",
    },
    {
        id: 11,
        name: "Bluza2",
        image: "11.png",
        price: 2,
        href: "products/bluza2.html",
    },
    {
        id: 12,
        name: "Bluza3",
        image: "11.png",
        price: 3,
        href: "products/bluza3.html",
    },
    {
        id: 13,
        name: "Bluza4",
        image: "11.png",
        price: 4,
        href: "products/bluza4.html",
    },
    {
        id: 14,
        name: "Bluza5",
        image: "11.png",
        price: 5,
        href: "products/bluza5.html",
    },
    {
        id: 15,
        name: "Bluza6",
        image: "11.png",
        price: 6,
        href: "products/bluza6.html",
    },
    {
        id: 16,
        name: "Bluza7",
        image: "11.png",
        price: 7,
        href: "products/bluza7.html",
    },
    {
        id: 17,
        name: "Bluza8",
        image: "11.png",
        price: 8,
        href: "products/bluza8.html",
    },
    {
        id: 18,
        name: "Bluza9",
        image: "11.png",
        price: 9,
        href: "products/bluza9.html",
    },
    {
        id: 19,
        name: "Bluza10",
        image: "11.png",
        price: 10,
        href: "products/bluza10.html",
    },
    {
        id: 20,
        name: "Tricou1",
        image: "21.png",
        price: 1,
        href: "products/tricou1.html",
    },
    {
        id: 21,
        name: "Tricou2",
        image: "21.png",
        price: 2,
        href: "products/tricou2.html",
    },
    {
        id: 22,
        name: "Tricou3",
        image: "21.png",
        price: 3,
        href: "products/tricou3.html",
    },
    {
        id: 23,
        name: "Tricou4",
        image: "21.png",
        price: 4,
        href: "products/tricou4.html",
    },
    {
        id: 24,
        name: "Tricou5",
        image: "21.png",
        price: 5,
        href: "products/tricou5.html",
    },
    {
        id: 25,
        name: "Tricou6",
        image: "21.png",
        price: 6,
        href: "products/tricou6.html",
    },
    {
        id: 26,
        name: "Tricou7",
        image: "21.png",
        price: 7,
        href: "products/tricou7.html",
    },
    {
        id: 27,
        name: "Tricou8",
        image: "21.png",
        price: 8,
        href: "products/tricou8.html",
    },
    {
        id: 28,
        name: "Tricou9",
        image: "21.png",
        price: 9,
        href: "products/tricou9.html",
    },
    {
        id: 29,
        name: "Tricou10",
        image: "21.png",
        price: 10,
        href: "products/tricou10.html",
    },
    {
        id: 30,
        name: "Sapca1",
        image: "31.png",
        price: 1,
        href: "products/sapca1.html",
    },
    {
        id: 31,
        name: "Sapca2",
        image: "31.png",
        price: 2,
        href: "products/sapca2.html",
    },
    {
        id: 32,
        name: "Sapca3",
        image: "31.png",
        price: 3,
        href: "products/sapca3.html",
    },
    {
        id: 33,
        name: "Sapca4",
        image: "31.png",
        price: 4,
        href: "products/sapca4.html",
    },
    {
        id: 34,
        name: "Sapca5",
        image: "31.png",
        price: 5,
        href: "products/sapca5.html",
    },
    {
        id: 35,
        name: "Sapca6",
        image: "31.png",
        price: 6,
        href: "products/sapca6.html",
    },
    {
        id: 36,
        name: "Sapca7",
        image: "31.png",
        price: 7,
        href: "products/sapca7.html",
    },
    {
        id: 37,
        name: "Sapca8",
        image: "31.png",
        price: 8,
        href: "products/sapca8.html",
    },
    {
        id: 38,
        name: "Sapca9",
        image: "31.png",
        price: 9,
        href: "products/sapca9.html",
    },
    {
        id: 39,
        name: "Sapca10",
        image: "31.png",
        price: 10,
        href: "products/sapca10.html",
    },
    {
        id: 40,
        name: "Stikere1",
        image: "41.png",
        price: 1,
        href: "products/stikere1.html",
    },
    {
        id: 41,
        name: "Stikere2",
        image: "41.png",
        price: 2,
        href: "products/stikere2.html",
    },
    {
        id: 42,
        name: "Stikere3",
        image: "41.png",
        price: 3,
        href: "products/stikere3.html",
    },
    {
        id: 43,
        name: "Stikere4",
        image: "41.png",
        price: 4,
        href: "products/stikere4.html",
    },
    {
        id: 44,
        name: "Stikere5",
        image: "41.png",
        price: 5,
        href: "products/stikere5.html",
    },
    {
        id: 45,
        name: "Stikere6",
        image: "41.png",
        price: 6,
        href: "products/stikere6.html",
    },
    {
        id: 46,
        name: "Stikere7",
        image: "41.png",
        price: 7,
        href: "products/stikere7.html",
    },
    {
        id: 47,
        name: "Stikere8",
        image: "41.png",
        price: 8,
        href: "products/stikere8.html",
    },
    {
        id: 48,
        name: "Stikere9",
        image: "41.png",
        price: 9,
        href: "products/stikere9.html",
    },
    {
        id: 49,
        name: "Stikere10",
        image: "41.png",
        price: 10,
        href: "products/stikere10.html",
    },
];

let listCartProducts = [];

function initApp(limit) {
    const productArray = [...productsAll];
    const categories = [
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
        [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
        [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49],
    ];

    const categoryNames = ["Hanorace", "Bluze", "Tricouri", "Sepci", "Stikere"];

    categories.forEach((category, categoryIndex) => {
        let categoryDiv = document.createElement("div");
        categoryDiv.classList.add("category-container");
        categoryDiv.innerHTML = `<div class="category-title"><span>${categoryNames[categoryIndex]}</span></div>
                <div class="products-container"></div>`;
        let productsContainer = categoryDiv.querySelector(".products-container");

        productArray.slice(category[0], category[1] + 1).forEach((value, key) => {
            let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
            newDiv.classList.add("product");
            newDiv.innerHTML = `
                <div class="product-thumbnail"><a href="${value.href}"><img src="image/${
                value.image
            }"></a></div>
                <div class="product-title"><a href="${value.href}">${value.name}</a></div>
                <div class="product-price">${value.price.toLocaleString()}<span>Lei</span></div>
                <div class="product-button-container"><button class="product-button" onclick="addToCart(${categoryIndex}, ${key})"><i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i>Add To Cart</button></div>
                `;
            productsContainer.appendChild(newDiv);
        });

        list.appendChild(categoryDiv);
    });
}

initApp();

function addToCart(categoryIndex, key) {
    let productIndex = categoryIndex + key;
    if (listCartProducts[productIndex] == null) {
        listCartProducts[productIndex] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(productsAll[productIndex]));
        listCartProducts[productIndex].quantity = 1;
        listCartProducts[productIndex].originalPrice = productsAll[productIndex].price;
    } else {
        listCartProducts[productIndex].quantity++;
    }
    reloadCart();
}

function reloadCart() {
    listCart.innerHTML = "";
    let count = 0;
    let totalPrice = 0;
    listCartProducts.forEach((value, key) => {
        totalPrice += value.originalPrice * value.quantity;
        count += value.quantity;
        if (value != null) {
            let newDiv = document.createElement("li");
            newDiv.innerHTML = `
                        <div class="cart-product-thumbnail"><a href="${
                            value.href
                        }"><img src="image/${value.image}"/></a></div>
                        <div class="cart-product-name"><a href="${value.href}">${
                value.name
            }</a></div>
                        <div class="cart-product-price">${value.originalPrice.toLocaleString()}<span>Lei</span>
                        <button class="delete-product" title="Elimina produsul" onclick="deleteProduct(${key})"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash fa-2x"></i></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cart-product-quantity">
                            <button onclick="changeQuantity(${key}, ${
                value.quantity - 1
            })">-</button>
                            <div class="count">${value.quantity}</div>
                            <button onclick="changeQuantity(${key}, ${
                value.quantity + 1
            })">+</button>
                        </div>`;
            listCart.appendChild(newDiv);
        }
    });
    total.innerHTML = `<span class="total-title">Total:</span><span class="total-amount">${totalPrice.toLocaleString()}</span><span class="total-currency">Lei</span>`;
    quantity.innerText = count;
}

function changeQuantity(key, quantity) {
    if (quantity === 0) {
        delete listCartProducts[key];
    } else {
        const product = listCartProducts[key];
        const originalPrice = productsAll[key].price;
        product.quantity = quantity;
        product.price = originalPrice * quantity;
    }
    reloadCart();
}

function deleteProduct(key) {
    delete listCartProducts[key];
    reloadCart();
}
```

Comment: Ensuring unique values are added to a list (so duplicates are not added) is super simple in most programming languages with a `Set()` as the datatype does not allow duplicates...Here is an overview that shows your solution via W3: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_sets.asp#:~:text=A%20JavaScript%20Set%20is%20a,value%20of%20any%20data%20type.

Comment: Post code as a [mcve] so it won't be so difficult trying to figure out the problem and easier to test. Add the HTML as well.

Answer (score 1):

`document.querySelector()` returns first element in the document having the provided query. If multiple elements are there in the document having a particular attribute you have to use `document.querySelectorAll()`. It returns a NodeList. You can select a particular element using `document.querySelectorAll()[i]` where i is the index. For example,

- To select first element `document.querySelectorAll()[0]`
- To select second element `document.querySelectorAll()[1]`

and so on...

Hope you find this useful!